# How to scale a texture in webgl?

Tags: matrix, webgl, aspect-ratio

I have a texture of size 800x600. How do I scale it on a webgl `<canvas>`  at another size and keep the original aspect ratio? Assuming that the drawing buffer and the canvas have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the WebGL only cares about clipsapce coordinates you can just draw a 2 unit quad (-1 to +1) and scale it by the aspect of the canvas vs the aspect of the image.

In other words

```
  const canvasAspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
  const imageAspect = image.width / image.height;

  let scaleY = 1;
  let scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
```

Note that you need to decide how you want to fit the image. `scaleY= 1` means the image will always fit vertically and horizontally will just be whatever it comes out to.

If you want it to fit horizontally then you need to make scaleX = 1

```
  let scaleX = 1;
  let scaleY = canvasAspect / imageAspect;
```

If you want it to `contain` then

```
  let scaleY = 1;
  let scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
  if (scaleX > 1) {
    scaleY = 1 / scaleX;
    scaleX = 1;
  }
```

If you want it to `cover` then

```
  let scaleY = 1;
  let scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
  if (scaleX < 1) {
    scaleY = 1 / scaleX;
    scaleX = 1;
  }
```

```js
let scaleMode = 'fitV';

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;  // because we know we're using a -1 + 1 quad
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_tex, v_texcoord);
}
`;

let image = { width: 1, height: 1 }; // dummy until loaded
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: 'https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
}, (err, tex, img) => {
  // called after image as loaded
  image = img;
  render();
});

const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      -1, -1,  // tri 1
       1, -1,
      -1,  1,      
      -1,  1,  // tri 2
       1, -1,
       1,  1,
    ],
  }
});


function render() {
  // this line is not needed if you don't
  // care that the canvas drawing buffer size
  // matches the canvas display size
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  const canvasAspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const imageAspect = image.width / image.height;
  let scaleX;
  let scaleY;

  switch (scaleMode) {
    case 'fitV':
      scaleY = 1;
      scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
      break;
    case 'fitH':
      scaleX = 1;
      scaleY = canvasAspect / imageAspect;
      break;
    case 'contain':
      scaleY = 1;
      scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
      if (scaleX > 1) {
        scaleY = 1 / scaleX;
        scaleX = 1;
      }
      break;
    case 'cover':
      scaleY = 1;
      scaleX = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
      if (scaleX < 1) {
        scaleY = 1 / scaleX;
        scaleX = 1;
      }
      break;
  }
  
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_matrix: [
      scaleX, 0, 0, 0,
      0, -scaleY, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1,
    ],
  });
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

render();
window.addEventListener('resize', render);
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', setScaleMode);
});

function setScaleMode(e) {
 scaleMode = e.target.id;
 render();
}
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.ui {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div class="ui">
  <button id="fitV">fit vertical</button>
  <button id="fitH">fit horizontal</button>
  <button id="contain">contain</button>
  <button id="cover">cover</button>
</div>
```

The code above uses a 4x4 matrix to apply the scale

```
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
```

It could just as easily pass in the scale directly

```
  uniform vec2 scale;
  ...
  gl_Position = vec4(scale * position.xy, 0, 1);
```

Comment: I can't really understand this part:

`v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;`

(in fact If I omit it I get texture stretched with edge repeated).

Comment: the position coordinates go from -1 to +1. multiplying by .5 and adding .5 makes them go from 0 to 1 which is what you want to show the entire texture across the quad . see https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html

Comment: Can i get some pointers on how did you get the scaling formulas?.I am stuck with a scaling problem recently..I am stretching in x direction i.e, horizontally with some value and doing scaleY=scaleX/Aspect ratio of image..Here scaleX is just some number..Image is scaled but looking stretched out in X direction

Comment: there are 2 aspects. The aspect of the canvas and the aspect of the image (there's also the aspect of the quad coordinates but in the example above its aspect is 1.0 and so can be ignored). Setting scaleY = 1 and scaleX = 1/canvasAspect would make the quad itself square when drawn on the canvas. But we need it scaled to be the imageAspect on that canvas. You should post your code as a snippet in a new question.