# WebGL canvas background

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, shader, webgl

I would like to simply add a "sky" background in my scene so that it won't cover the objects but just being visible after them.

I've tried to, but I have no idea to do it without applying it over the other objects drawn in the scene.

Unfortunately I've to do all this without using any advanced library such as three.js and so on.

The background I'd like to use is in /Assets/sky.jpg

Here the js file:

```html
var program0;
var program1;
var gl;
var shaderDir;
var baseDir;
var lastUpdateTime;

var boatModel;
var rockModel;
var rock2Model;
var oceanModel;





var object = [];

//attributes and uniforms
var positionAttributeLocation = Array();
var uvAttributeLocation = Array();
var matrixLocation = Array();
var textLocation = Array();
var normalAttributeLocation = Array();
var normalMatrixPositionHandle = Array();
var worldViewMatrixLocation = Array();
var worldViewMatrixLocation_transpose = Array();

var materialDiffColorHandle = Array();
var lightDirectionHandle = Array();
var lightColorHandle = Array();
var ambientLightcolorHandle = Array();
var specularColorHandle = Array();
var specShineHandle = Array();


var vaos = new Array();
var textures = new Array();
var modelStr = Array();
var modelTexture = Array();

//matrices
var viewMatrix;
var perspectiveMatrix;

//lights
//define directional light
var dirLightAlpha = -utils.degToRad(180);
var dirLightBeta = -utils.degToRad(100);
var directionalLight;
var directionalLightColor;
var ambientLight = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
var specularColor = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0];
var specShine = 0.0;

//camera
var cx = 0;
var cy = 0;
var cz = 1;
var camAngle = 0;
var camElev = 5;

//boat kinematics
var linearDir = 0;
var linearVel = 0;
var velX = 0;
var velZ = 0;
var maxLinearVel = 0.01;
var linearAcc = 0.0001;
var linearDrag = 0.005;

var turningDir = 0;
var angularVel = 0.0;
var maxAngularVel = 0.2;
var angularAcc = 0.01;
var angularDrag = 0.01;

modelStr[0] = 'Assets/Boat/Boat.obj';
modelStr[1] = 'Assets/Rocks/Rock1/rock1.obj';
modelStr[2] = 'Assets/Rocks/Rock2/Rock_1.obj';
modelStr[3] = 'Assets/ocean-obj/ocean.obj';
//modelStr[3] = 'Assets/ocean2/hdri-ca-sky.obj';

modelTexture[0] = 'Assets/Boat/textures/boat_diffuse.bmp';
modelTexture[1] = 'Assets/Rocks/Rock1/textures/rock_low_Base_Color.png';
modelTexture[2] = 'Assets/Rocks/Rock2/Rock_1_Tex/Rock_1_Base_Color.jpg';
modelTexture[3] = 'Assets/ocean-obj/woter.jpg';
//modelTexture[3] = 'Assets/ocean2/CA-Sky-2016-04-15-11-30-am.jpg';

modelTexture[4] = 'Assets/Sea/sea.jpg'

var nFrame = 0;


/***********************************************************************************************/

class Item {
  x; y; z;
  Rx; Ry; Rz;
  S;

  vertices;
  normals;
  indices;
  texCoords;

  materialColor;


  constructor(x, y, z, Rx, Ry, Rz, S) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.Rx = Rx;
    this.Ry = Ry;
    this.Rz = Rz;
    this.S = S;



  }

  buildWorldMatrix() {
    return utils.MakeWorld(this.x, this.y, this.z, this.Rx, this.Ry, this.Rz, this.S);

  }


  setAttr(objectVertices, objectNormals, objectIndices, objectTexCoords) {
    this.vertices = objectVertices;
    this.normals = objectNormals;
    this.indices = objectIndices;
    this.texCoords = objectTexCoords;

  }

  setMaterialColor(materialColorArray) {
    this.materialColor = materialColorArray;

  }


}

//objects
var rock = new Item(1.0, -0.5, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 20.0);
var boat = new Item(0.0, -0.15, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 1000.0);
var rock2 = new Item(-1.0, -0.4, -3, -30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 10.0);
var ocean = new Item(0.0, -0.02, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0);

function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}

function main() {

  utils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  setFloorCoord();
  /* Load corresponding information from the models */
  object[0] = boat;
  object[1] = rock;
  object[2] = rock2;
  object[3] = ocean;

  boat.setAttr(boatModel.vertices, boatModel.vertexNormals, boatModel.indices, boatModel.textures);
  boat.setMaterialColor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]); // set material color for boat

  rock.setAttr(rockModel.vertices, rockModel.vertexNormals, rockModel.indices, rockModel.textures);
  rock.setMaterialColor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]); // set material color for rock

  rock2.setAttr(rock2Model.vertices, rock2Model.vertexNormals, rock2Model.indices, rock2Model.textures);
  rock2.setMaterialColor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

  ocean.setAttr(oceanModel.vertices, oceanModel.vertexNormals, oceanModel.indices, oceanModel.textures);
  ocean.setMaterialColor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);



  directionalLight = [Math.cos(dirLightAlpha) * Math.cos(dirLightBeta),
  Math.sin(dirLightAlpha),
  Math.cos(dirLightAlpha) * Math.sin(dirLightBeta)
  ];
  directionalLightColor = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];

  /* Retrieve the position of the attributes and uniforms */
  getShadersPos()

  objectWorldMatrix = Array();

  objectWorldMatrix[0] = boat.buildWorldMatrix(); //boat WorldMatrix
  objectWorldMatrix[1] = rock.buildWorldMatrix(); //rock WorlMatrix
  objectWorldMatrix[2] = rock2.buildWorldMatrix();
  objectWorldMatrix[3] = ocean.buildWorldMatrix();


  perspectiveMatrix = utils.MakePerspective(90, gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0);
  viewMatrix = utils.MakeView(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 15.0, 0.0);

  setBuffers();
  drawScene();

}

async function init() {

  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var page = path.split("/").pop();
  baseDir = window.location.href.replace(page, '');
  shaderDir = baseDir + "shaders/";

  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");


  lastUpdateTime = (new Date).getTime();

  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    document.write("GL context not opened");
    return;
  }

  

  await utils.loadFiles([shaderDir + 'vs.glsl', shaderDir + 'fs.glsl'], function (shaderText) {
    var vertexShader = utils.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, shaderText[0]);
    var fragmentShader = utils.createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderText[1]);
    program0 = utils.createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

  });

  await utils.loadFiles([shaderDir + 'vs_unlit.glsl', shaderDir + 'fs_unlit.glsl'], function (shaderText) {
    var vertexShader = utils.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, shaderText[0]);
    var fragmentShader = utils.createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderText[1]);

    program1 = utils.createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
  });



  //###################################################################################
  //This loads the obj model in the boatModel variable
  var boatObjStr = await utils.get_objstr(baseDir + modelStr[0]);
  boatModel = new OBJ.Mesh(boatObjStr);
  //###################################################################################

  //###################################################################################
  //This loads the obj model in the rockModel variable
  var rockObjStr = await utils.get_objstr(baseDir + modelStr[1]);
  rockModel = new OBJ.Mesh(rockObjStr);
  //###################################################################################

  //###################################################################################
  //This loads the obj model in the rockModel variable
  var rock2ObjStr = await utils.get_objstr(baseDir + modelStr[2]);
  rock2Model = new OBJ.Mesh(rock2ObjStr);
  //###################################################################################

  var oceanObjStr = await utils.get_objstr(baseDir + modelStr[3]);
  oceanModel = new OBJ.Mesh(oceanObjStr);

  initControls(canvas);

  main();
}



function getShadersPos() {
  positionAttributeLocation[0] = gl.getAttribLocation(program0, "a_position");
  uvAttributeLocation[0] = gl.getAttribLocation(program0, "a_uv");
  matrixLocation[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, "matrix");
  worldViewMatrixLocation[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, "worldviewmatrix");
  worldViewMatrixLocation_transpose[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, "worldviewmatrix_t");
  textLocation[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, "u_texture");
  normalAttributeLocation[0] = gl.getAttribLocation(program0, "inNormal");
  normalMatrixPositionHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'nMatrix');

  materialDiffColorHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'mDiffColor');
  lightDirectionHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'lightDirection');
  lightColorHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'lightColor');
  ambientLightcolorHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'ambientLightcolor');
  specularColorHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'specularColor');
  specShineHandle[0] = gl.getUniformLocation(program0, 'SpecShine');

  
}

function setBuffers() {

  for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {

    vaos[i] = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vaos[i])

    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(object[i].vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation[0]);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation[0], 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(object[i].texCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uvAttributeLocation[0]);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvAttributeLocation[0], 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(object[i].indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(object[i].normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normalAttributeLocation[0]);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(normalAttributeLocation[0], 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    textures[i] = gl.createTexture();

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

    image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.src = baseDir + modelTexture[i];

    image.onload = function (texture, image) {
      return function () {
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0)
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        // Check if the image is a power of 2 in both dimensions.
        if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
          // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
          gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        } else {
          // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn off mips and set wrapping to clamp to edge
          gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
          gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
          gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        }
      };
    }(textures[i], image);

  }
}



function drawObjects() {
  for (let i = 0; i < object.length; ++i) {
    gl.useProgram(program0);
    var viewWorldMatrix = utils.multiplyMatrices(viewMatrix, objectWorldMatrix[i]);
    var projectionMatrix = utils.multiplyMatrices(perspectiveMatrix, viewWorldMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation[0], gl.FALSE, utils.transposeMatrix(projectionMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldViewMatrixLocation_transpose[0], gl.FALSE, utils.transposeMatrix(utils.invertMatrix(utils.transposeMatrix(viewWorldMatrix))));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldViewMatrixLocation[0], gl.FALSE, utils.transposeMatrix(viewWorldMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(normalMatrixPositionHandle[0], gl.FALSE, utils.transposeMatrix(utils.invertMatrix(utils.transposeMatrix(objectWorldMatrix[i]))));

    gl.uniform3fv(materialDiffColorHandle[0], object[i].materialColor);
    gl.uniform3fv(lightColorHandle[0], directionalLightColor);
    gl.uniform3fv(lightDirectionHandle[0], directionalLight);
    gl.uniform3fv(ambientLightcolorHandle[0], ambientLight);
    gl.uniform3fv(specularColorHandle[0], specularColor);
    gl.uniform1f(specShineHandle[0], specShine);


    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
    gl.uniform1i(textLocation[0], textures[i]);


    gl.bindVertexArray(vaos[i]);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, object[i].indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  }

  
}

var counter = 0;

function animate(item) {
  var currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
  if (lastUpdateTime != null) {
    boatDynamic(currentTime);
    var deltaC = (30 * (currentTime - lastUpdateTime)) / 1000.0;
    //item.z += deltaC/100;


    //item.Rz += deltaC;
  }

  /* depending on which object we want to animate we change the worldmatrix of the object */
  //objectWorldMatrix[0] = utils.MakeWorld(0.0, item.y, item.z, item.Rx, item.Ry, item.Rz, item.S);
  counter += 0.005;
  //item.z = counter % 2;
  //item.y = counter;

  //(0, -1, 2, 45, 0)
  //item.z -= 0.002;
  viewMatrix = utils.MakeView(cx + item.x, cy + 1, 2 + item.z, camElev, 0);

  //<---- la barca si muove verso la z negativa
  //item.y += 0.002;

  objectWorldMatrix[0] = item.buildWorldMatrix();


  //objectWorldMatrix[1] = rock.buildWorldMatrix();
  //objectWorldMatrix[2] = rock2.buildWorldMatrix();
  lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}

function drawScene() {

  animate(boat);

  gl.clearColor(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  

  // DRAW THE OBJECTS IN THE SCENE
  drawObjects();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}

//controls
var keys = [];
var vz = 0.0;
var rvy = 0.0;

var keyFunctionDown = function (e) {
  if (!keys[e.keyCode]) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37: //LEFT ARROW KEY DOWN
        turningDir = - 1;
        break;

      case 39: //RIGHT ARROW KEY DOWN
        turningDir = + 1;
        break;

      case 38: //UP ARROW KEY DOWN
        linearDir = + 1;
        break;

      case 40: //DOWN ARROW KEY DOWN
        linearDir = - 1;

        break;

      //camera controls
      case 87:
        camElev += 5;
        console.log(camElev)
        break;
      case 83:
        camElev -= 5;
        console.log(camElev)
        break;
    }
  }
}

var keyFunctionUp = function (e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37: //LEFT ARROW KEY UP
        turningDir = 0;
        break;
      case 39: //RIGHT ARROW KEY UP
        turningDir = 0;
        break;
      case 38: //UP ARROW KEY UP
        linearDir = 0;
        break;
      case 40: //DOWN ARROW KEY DOWN
        linearDir = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}

function initControls(canvas) {
  window.addEventListener("keyup", keyFunctionUp, false);
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyFunctionDown, false);


}


function boatDynamic(currentTime) {
  //console.log(linearVel);
  //boat turning
  angularVel += turningDir * angularAcc;
  if (Math.abs(angularVel) >= maxAngularVel)
    angularVel = Math.sign(angularVel) * maxAngularVel;

  //angular velocity degradation
  angularVel = angularVel * (1 - angularDrag);

  boat.Rx += angularVel;

  //boat speed
  linearVel += linearDir * linearAcc;
  if (Math.abs(linearVel) >= maxLinearVel)
    linearVel = Math.sign(linearVel) * maxLinearVel;

  //linear vel degradation
  linearVel = linearVel * (1 - linearDrag)

  //linear velocity axis decomposition
  velX = - linearVel * Math.cos(utils.degToRad(boat.Rx));
  velZ = - linearVel * Math.sin(utils.degToRad(boat.Rx));



  boat.x += velX;
  boat.z += velZ;


  //simple boat "wobbling" around its y axis, must be implemented better
  if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
    boat.Ry += Math.sin(utils.degToRad(currentTime)) / 8;
  }

}


function dirLightChange(value, type) {
  if (type == 'alpha')
    dirLightAlpha = -utils.degToRad(value);
  else
    dirLightBeta = -utils.degToRad(value);

  directionalLight = [Math.cos(dirLightAlpha) * Math.cos(dirLightBeta),
  Math.sin(dirLightAlpha),
  Math.cos(dirLightAlpha) * Math.sin(dirLightBeta)
  ];
  drawObjects();


}

function onColorChange(value, type) {
  let result = HEX2RGB(value);
  var r = result[0] / 255.0;
  var g = result[1] / 255.0;
  var b = result[2] / 255.0;
  if (type == 'ambient')
    ambientLight = [r, g, b];
  else if (type == 'directional')
    directionalLightColor = [r, g, b];
  else if (type == 'material')
    boat.setMaterialColor([r, g, b]);
  else
    specularColor = [r, g, b];
  drawObjects();
}

function onSpecShineChange(value) {
  specShine = value;
  drawObjects();
}


window.onload = init;
```

Here the repo with the entire project: [repo](https://github.com/andreamur95/so_help)

Comment: you may draw rect whith min z value, and set your texture on it

Answer (score 0):

- method 1 easiest

  1. clear the depth buffer
  2. turn off the depth test
  3. draw a plane with your sky texture
  4. turn on the depth test
  5. draw your objects
- method 2 (slightly more efficient)

  1. clear the depth buffer
  2. set depth func to `LESS`
  3. turn on the depth test
  4. draw your opaque objects
  5. set depth func to `LEQUAL`
  6. draw a plane with your sky texture at Z = 1
  7. draw your transparent objects

Note: drawing a plane at Z = 1 is easiest with a custom shader that just does that.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508687/128511

Many old outdated 3D engines try to use the system that draws everything else. In other words they only implement one thing, a loop that draws all objects with a single projection matrix and view matrix, so they have to compute a model matrix that positions the plane so that it just happens to show up at -Z in the current view and the current projection. That's silly IMO.

Another thing slightly less outdated 3D engines do is let each object the draw use a different projection and view matrix. In that case projections and view matrices for the planes can be set to something like (assuming the plane has vertices at Z = 0

```
   view matrix = identity
   projection matrix = [
      1, 0, 0, 0
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 1,
   ];

  Will move Z to 1.
```

You then probably want to set the first 1 (width) and second 1 (height) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508687/128511) (same as above)

If it was me though I'd do what modern engines do and use a different shader like the one in the first link above just for drawing an image.

Note: you might also want to look into [skyboxes](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skybox.html)

Comment: The problem is that the environment is going to change, my objects are going to move in the environment, so I need a sort of fixed background during all the time avoiding to moving it with other objects.
Does skyboxes achieve this? how to create them without using more advanced library? What you suggest then?

Comment: The answer above is about fixed backgrounds. Only the note at the bottom is suggesting you might want to look into skyboxes. If you want a fixed background use the solutions suggested in the answer. If you want a skybox follow the linked article. There are [lots of free images here](https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/) and [here's a converter to convert them to cubemaps](https://matheowis.github.io/HDRI-to-CubeMap/)